# I have set developer mode and when i create product its showing error in front end shopware.

Tags: product, shopware

I have set developer mode and when i create product its showing error in front end shopware.

[image]

[image]

I am getting below error

> Call to a member function isExpressCheckoutEnabled() on null in
>
> /var/www/html/var/cache/production_201807181357/templates/frontend_Responsive_en_GB_1_secure/d4/34/dd/d434ddfa8933da31154ad7654f3ecb3532692b97.snippet.index.tpl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the amazon pay plugin. Try to deactivate the plugin and clear all caches.

Comment: Perfect Thank you :)